# Codename One: How to connect SQLite to a picker component and add a string to a time picker component

Tags: codenameone

1. How can I populate a picker (accepting strings) using items in an external SQLite database? [View of picker (accepting strings) to be populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHlUw.jpg)
2. How can I add a string to a time picker to indicate to a user what time they need to select? The user needs to select two times (start and end) and I would like to indicate to the user which one they need to select for each time picker [View of the two times to be chosen by the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfiVD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can populate a String [Picker](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.html) using:

```
stringPicker.setStrings("A Game of Thrones", "A Clash Of Kings", "A Storm Of Swords", "A Feast For Crows",
        "A Dance With Dragons", "The Winds of Winter", "A Dream of Spring");
stringPicker.setSelectedString("A Game of Thrones");
```

This code is from the [Picker JavaDocs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.html).

You can query sqlite via the db API covered [here (JavaDoc)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/db/package-summary.html) & [here (Developer Guide)](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html#_sql):

```
    Database db = null;
    Cursor cur = null;
    try {
        db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("MyDB.db");
        if(query.getText().startsWith("select")) {
            cur = db.executeQuery(query.getText());
            int columns = cur.getColumnCount();
            hi.removeAll();
            if(columns > 0) {
                boolean next = cur.next();
                if(next) {
                    ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
                    String[] columnNames = new String[columns];
                    for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                        columnNames[iter] = cur.getColumnName(iter);
                    }
                    while(next) {
                        Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
                        String[] currentRowArray = new String[columns];
                        for(int iter = 0 ; iter < columns ; iter++) {
                            currentRowArray[iter] = currentRow.getString(iter);
                        }
                        data.add(currentRowArray);
                        next = cur.next();
                    }
                    Object[][] arr = new Object[data.size()][];
                    data.toArray(arr);
                    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Table(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, arr)));
                } else {
                    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query returned no results");
                }
            } else {
                hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query returned no results");
            }
        } else {
            db.execute(query.getText());
            hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Query completed successfully");
        }
        hi.revalidate();
    } catch(IOException err) {
        Log.e(err);
        hi.removeAll();
        hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, "Error: " + err);
        hi.revalidate();
    } finally {
        Util.cleanup(db);
        Util.cleanup(cur);
    }
```

You can't change the look of the time picker as it will look like this on Android:

[image: Time picker for Android]

However, if you are talking about the UI showing the hour before actually launching you can customize that by overriding [updateValue](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.html#updateValue--).

Comment: Thanks. However, once I made the changes, I received error messages, including the following: [EDT] 0:0:0,0 - Exception: java.io.IOException - [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ".": syntax error). This could be due to the application not recognising my database. To clarify, where exactly do I need to save my database file?

Comment: I suggest filing a question with details about the specific SQL access issue you are having, specific exception stack trace and what you are trying to do. E.g. what do you mean by "placing the database".